# What is wrong in this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, datetime, prestashop

I´m trying to get carts form 1 table, with just 1 condition, that is the next one "the cart has to be newer than any order with that same id_user"

```
SELECT pso.*
FROM lafrips_cart pso
WHERE pso.id_customer > 0 
AND pso.date_add > (SELECT MAX(pso2.date_add)
FROM lafrips_orders pso2
WHERE pso2.id_customer < pso.id_customer)
```

Im just comparing 2 fields (pso.date_add with ps2.date_add) both are datetime with the same structure

Comment: If they have to have the same user id, why are you saying `WHERE pso2.id_customer < pso.id_customer` instead of `=`?  Or am I not understanding something about your structure?

Comment: Please provide sample data and your expected output

Comment: It has been in my front everytime... wow...@Siyual that´s the error...

Comment: I'd suggest the queries problem is that its attached to a malformed question. It would be good if you indicated actual output and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pso.*
FROM lafrips_cart pso
WHERE 
    pso.id_customer > 0 
    AND pso.date_add > (
        SELECT MAX(pso2.date_add)
        FROM lafrips_orders pso2
        WHERE pso2.id_customer = pso.id_customer
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

As u both said @Siyual and @Sergio ">" was the error, actually I think I´m thick as a brick, I may have to sleep some more hours

```
SELECT pso.*
FROM lafrips_cart pso
WHERE
pso.id_customer > 0 
AND pso.date_add > (
    SELECT MAX(pso2.date_add)
    FROM lafrips_orders pso2
    WHERE pso2.id_customer **=** pso.id_customer
    )
```

Marked with ** the  = symbol replaced